Why the SSAS after restart of windows server is generating errors 'Errors in the metadata manager. An error occurred when loading the 'X' cube'?
On one of the windows server where SQL Server with SSAS is running and some demo application is using the MDX to query the dimensional database on SSAS, we are running into weird behavior.
When the server is restarted, the SSAS is logging the following on each query:

The error is:

Errors in the metadata manager. An error occurred when loading the 'Model' cube, from the file, '\?\F:\data\OLAP...\Model.51.cub.xml'.

What helps is to connect using SSMS and the problem is gone.
Few additional notes:

the time between restart and first query can be more than 5 hours
the version is 15.0.35.33
queries can than run for several hours from the app and the error persists
the server has nothing non-ordinary configured, only DataDir and LogDir are on F: drive instead of default (not TempDir or BackupDir though which is kind of weird)
the databases are relatively small 4 x cca 1GB
I am planning to check what is in the problematic xml file, but as of now I can not manually restart the server to repro and check

Does anybody have some clue why this can be happening?
There are few interesting articles slightly related but so far nothing helpful:

How to fix 'error in the metadata manager dimension id of missing ' error in SSAS?
https://www.nigeldba.com/ssas-force-into-loading-databases
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/67703/file-system-error-errors-in-the-metadata-manager-p
https://thedailydba.wordpress.com/2016/01/14/ssis-errors-in-the-metadata-manager/

